# Android App Crashing whenever progressDialog is canceled

Tags: android

My app crashes and says "unfortunately  has stopped" whenever i cancel/dismiss the progress dialo during a HTTP connection or whenever the server is unreachable due to slow internet. Here is the class, XML and logCat:

```
package com.abc123;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;





public class Result extends ListActivity {

//final String category = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1)).getSelectedItem().toString();
//final String location = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2)).getSelectedItem().toString();
String category = "Furniture";
String location = "Kugbo";

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private String url_all_products = "localhost://abc.com.ng/123.php?category="+category+"&location="+location;
    category="+category+"&location="+location;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "data"; 
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();      

        // Loading results in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();


    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();        
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Result.this);
            //pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_img));
            pDialog.setMessage("we don dey reach...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);          
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();  

            }


        /**
         * getting results from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);


            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Results: ", json.toString());


            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // results returned
                    // Getting Array of results
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through results
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                        map.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                }       

                else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oops! No results for the search criteria", 3).show(); 

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting results
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Result.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME,
                                    TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_PHONE},
                            new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.address, R.id.phone });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }       

    }
}







XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:background="@color/resultPage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >

<!--<include layout="@layout/header" />-->
<include layout="@layout/footer_2" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroller"


        />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>





LOGCAT:

04-30 19:47:21.425: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:22.935: D/dalvikvm(1160): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 4% free 3616K/3752K, paused 143ms, total 148ms
04-30 19:47:23.635: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:24.935: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 805 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:25.565: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 316 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:26.035: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 264 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:26.635: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:26.735: W/InputEventReceiver(1160): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
04-30 19:47:26.735: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:28.265: W/System.err(1160): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /68.169.55.104:80 timed out
04-30 19:47:28.275: W/System.err(1160):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
04-30 19:47:28.275: W/System.err(1160):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-30 19:47:28.275: W/System.err(1160):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-30 19:47:28.285: W/System.err(1160):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-30 19:47:28.285: W/System.err(1160):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-30 19:47:28.285: W/System.err(1160):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-30 19:47:28.285: W/System.err(1160):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-30 19:47:28.295: W/System.err(1160):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-30 19:47:28.295: W/System.err(1160):     at com.insidetown.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:67)
04-30 19:47:28.295: W/System.err(1160):     at com.insidetown.Result$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Result.java:104)
04-30 19:47:28.295: W/System.err(1160):     at com.insidetown.Result$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Result.java:1)
04-30 19:47:28.295: W/System.err(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-30 19:47:28.305: W/System.err(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-30 19:47:28.305: W/System.err(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-30 19:47:28.315: W/System.err(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-30 19:47:28.315: W/System.err(1160):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-30 19:47:28.315: E/Buffer Error(1160): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
04-30 19:47:28.325: E/JSON Parser(1160): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-30 19:47:28.335: W/dalvikvm(1160): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4b10b90)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): Process: com.insidetown, PID: 1160
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at com.insidetown.Result$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Result.java:108)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at com.insidetown.Result$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Result.java:1)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-30 19:47:28.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     ... 3 more
04-30 19:47:29.235: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 426 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:29.335: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:31.165: I/Choreographer(1160): Skipped 169 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-30 19:47:36.685: I/Process(1160): Sending signal. PID: 1160 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What you are trying to do in onPostExecute()? onPostExecute already runs in main thread.

Comment: What I do in onPostExecute is to pupulate the listView with the contents of the ArrayList coming from the doInBackground method. If I allow the progressDialog to complete, the app works just fine, but i am trying to simulate a scenario where the user might decide to dismiss the progressDialog by pressing the back button, either due to impatience or slow network, so this should stop the onPostExecute from happening. But whenever i try dismissing the progressDialog prematurely, it actually dismisses it successfuly, but then in a moment the app displays "Unfortunately <app_name> has stopped"

Comment: Try these two things: 1. Set progressDialog.setOnClickListener() and cancel asynctask in it (mLoadAllProductsTask.cancel()) OR 2. Check isCancel() in doInBackground() and break; try these two if it doesnt work I will try to reproduce it on my machine. Lets get this thing fixed!

Comment: Thank you @araut i appreciate. i have actually looked at what you suggested, makes sense. Problem is that progressDialog doesnt implement OnclickListener, only onDismiss and onCancel. I used both do simulate what you advised but its saying i cant call cancel() on asyncTask. pls can u try this frm your own end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got time to do this today - Your AsyncTask should look something like this.

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();        
            //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CancelAsyncTask.this);
            //pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_img));
            //pDialog.setMessage("we don dey reach...");
            //pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);          
            //pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            //pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            //pDialog.show();  

            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    CancelAsyncTaskActivity.this,
                    "Title",
                    "we don dey reach...",
                    true,
                    true,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            // cancel the AsyncTask here!
                            mAsyncTask.cancel(true);
                        }
                    }
                    );

            }

        /**
         * getting results from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Do your background stuff here

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting results
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                }
            });

        }       

    }
```

Comment: @ araut thanks a lot! i really appreciate. I done it and its working, but I replaced the mAsyncTask with MyAsyncTask.this

Comment: Cool. mAsyncTask is reference in my MainiActivity to LoadAllProducts(AsyncTask). Anyways, could you please accept the answer, if this is the solution.

Comment: Accepted. pls would you also have a solution to this: i decide to allow the progressDialog to run normally but i intentionally cut off my data plan (but my WIFI and 3G are on) so that the app believes that network is available, i need the user to get a message through a Toast or something after the asynctask finishes running telling them that there's connection difficulty. Presently what happens is that when the asynctask is done running and there is no actual internet service, the pDialog dismisses and the app crashes

Comment: Thank you. You should post another question on SO - I will start looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

From your stacktrace it appears to be unrelated to the dialog, but rather a questionable response from the server that the code are trying to parse.

Perhaps there is a more complete stacktrace that shows what is happening if it did try to .dismiss() the dialog?

Comment: Am not sure but i guess the server response you are talking about from logcat is because the onPostExecute method did not run because i intentionally dismissed the progressDialog which inturn prematurely cut off the doInBackground process. If i let the progressDialog to run normally the app does not crash but i want to simulate a scenario where a user decides to prematurely cancel the progressDialog and return to the parent/previous activity